# Powershell launch window on second screen

Tags: powershell, window, launch

I need to launch two Google pages in full screen on a PC with 2 screens, one page for each screen.

Actually this is my code:

```
$pathToChrome = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
$tempFolder = '--user-data-dir=c:\temp' # pick a temp folder for user data
$startmode = '--start-fullscreen' # '--kiosk' is another option
$startPage1 = 'https://google.com'
$startPage2 = 'https://google.com'

Start-Process -FilePath $pathToChrome ('--new-window',  '--start-fullscreen', $startPage1) -ErrorVariable Test
Start-Process -FilePath $pathToChrome ('--new-window',  '--start-fullscreen', $startPage2) -ErrorVariable Test
```

It works but it open one page over the other one.
How can I do for open the second page on my second screen?

Comment: You could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41229932/is-it-possible-to-position-a-window-when-starting-a-process-with-powershell-sta) but specify the coordinates instead of getting them relative to the preselected screen. More ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392620/how-can-a-batch-file-run-a-program-and-set-the-position-and-size-of-the-window/).

Comment: Already saw this but I think there is a way to do it in a simple way, I know that you can check how many screens you have connected with:  [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::allscreens.length . Maybe is possible launch the page on each screen with a for cycle

Comment: The only ways (that I know about, at least) to set this _before_ the application is started would be 1) to pass the coordinates in the [`STARTUPINFO` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) to [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) [...]

Comment: [...] or 2) to pass a `HMONITOR` handle in the [`SHELLEXECUTEINFO` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shellexecuteinfow) to [`ShellExecuteEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexw). - Both of these things are not exposed to PowerShell though and you need to go through more P/Invoke magic for them.

Answer (score 0):

This is **application-specific** in Windows, unfortunately. Windows processes (like explorer.exe) all use startup info stored in the registry, but that is **not** a standard and many applications ignore it entirely.

The only real global way around it is to emulate moving the window manually using some user32.dll methods like CherryDT's comment suggests.

---

To answer your example, Chromium browsers can use start flags to specify position, but it requires running each window with separate profiles:

[How to open two instances of Chrome kiosk mode in different displays (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294045/how-to-open-two-instances-of-chrome-kiosk-mode-in-different-displays-windows)

[Launch Google Chrome from the command line with specific window coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19789383/7411885)

```sh
# open chrome on two monitors (all chrome windows must be closed first)
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app="http://www.domain1.com" --window-position=0,0 --kiosk --user-data-dir=c:/monitor1

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app="http://www.domain2.com" --window-position=1680,0 --kiosk --user-data-dir=c:/monitor2
```

---

I have found many other applications use a simple .ini file in appdata to store window size/location settings.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if this is still needed for someone, but i marge two scripts to one and now its working fine :)

```
    $pathToChrome = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
$tempFolder = '--user-data-dir=c:\temp' # pick a temp folder for user data
$startmode = '--start-fullscreen' # '--kiosk' is another option
$startPage1 = 'www.domain1.com'enter code here
$startPage2 = 'www.domain2.com'

Start-Process -FilePath $pathToChrome ('--new-window',  '--start-fullscreen', '--user-data-dir=c:/screen1','--window-position=1680,0', $startPage1) -ErrorVariable Test 
Start-Process -FilePath $pathToChrome ('--new-window',  '--start-fullscreen', '--user-data-dir=c:/screen2','--window-position=0,0', $startPage2) -ErrorVariable Test
```